# Unable to check if scanner input is in arraylist

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

this accesses an arraylist and there is code that does this same thing already and works fine

is there something wrong with my code here? or a way I can achieve this differently?

```
     System.out.println("Enter cruise ship name: ");
     String newCruiseShipName = newCruiseInfo.nextLine();           
        for(Ship eachShip:shipList) {
            if (eachShip.getShipName().equalsIgnoreCase(newCruiseName)){

            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Cruise ship not in service.");
                System.out.println("Exiting add cruise");
                returnMenu();
            }       

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should print the data side by side? Try using a debugger? Unit testing?

Comment: I don't know what `returnMenu()` does, but it's called for _the first element_ which does not return `true` for the `if` condition.

Comment: What does this `returnMenu()` do?
Isn't it stopping the for loop?

Comment: FYI - create `Set` of lowercased ship names and than use `contains`

Comment: return menu() is  a mehtod. I will post the whole driver

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are exiting in the first attempt if you cannot find a match based on "Exiting add cruise" line. May be you should also add returnMenu function, so that people can infer what your intention is.

anyways, if this is the case may be you should try something like this:

```
    System.out.println("Enter cruise ship name: ");
    String newCruiseShipName = newCruiseInfo.nextLine(); 
    boolean found = false;          
    for(Ship eachShip:shipList) {
        if (eachShip.getShipName().equalsIgnoreCase(newCruiseName)){
             found = true;
             break;
        }   
    }
   if (!found) {
      System.out.println("Cruise ship not in service.");
      System.out.println("Exiting add cruise");
      returnMenu();
   }
```

other possibilities are there can be whitespace in compared strings, or problems with getShipName etc.. may be trim works.

note: could not add comments due to reputation thing

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter cruise ship name: ");
String newCruiseShipName = newCruiseInfo.nextLine(); 

    if(!newCruiseShipName.contentEquals("")) {
        for(Ship eachShip: shipList) {
            if(eachShip.getInService()==true||eachShip.getShipName().equalsIgnoreCase(newCruiseShipName)) {

            }
            for(Cruise eachCruise:cruiseList) {
                if(eachCruise.getCruiseShipName().equalsIgnoreCase(newCruiseShipName)) {
                    System.out.println("Cruise Ship already assigned.");
                    System.out.println("Exiting add cruise");
                    returnMenu();
                    }break;
                }                   
        }
    }
```

it was nesting problem I was reducing my array size due to the order the for statements were in previously. I nested them and it solved my problem